# The oracle vs. oracledb tag

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

I see more and more questions using the [oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle) tag to target questions that are linked to the company Oracle (e.g. Java questions or other Oracle products), rather than their (main) database product.

As there also is an [oracledb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracledb) tag, I wonder if it makes sense to advocate [oracledb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracledb) over [oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle) to make it clear what exactly is meant. Maybe even make [oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle) a synonym for [oracledb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracledb)?

Comment: Oracle owns multiple DB solutions so the next question is which DB is oracledb referring to? I would guess that most people would associate the oracle database software with the name oracle without the need to add a db tag to it,

Comment: @JoeW: the other database products already have their own tags, e.g.  `mysql` or `rdb`, `berkeley-db`. Unfortunately their "flagship product" is named just like the company.

Comment: Would [oracle] even be an acceptable tag if it meant the company?

Comment: I don't think people will use [oracledb] or [oracle-server] or even [oracle-rdbms] because most oracle folks think that [oracle] means the database.  Changing the tag to not mean that will mean most likely mean more re-tagging work not less.

Answer (score 8):

According to the [oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle) tag wiki, it should be used for the oracle database, *not* oracle products. The [oracledb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracledb) tag is used for the exact same purposes as the [oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle) tag, so it seems wise to make [oracledb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracledb) a tag synonym for [oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle).

Comment: I know what the tag info says. But in my experience users (especially new users) do not read those infos.

Comment: Maybe it should be the other way around then, `oracle` remapped to `oracledb` to make it clearer

Comment: That's what my question is about: "*Maybe even make  `oracle` a synonym for `oracledb`"

Comment: I misunderstood you then. Maybe tag it with `synonym-request`.

Comment: I vote for this - make `oracledb` a synonym for `oracle`, not the other way around; historically, in a technical context, "oracle" always meant "the oracle database", even after later acquisitions. I've very rarely come across "oracledb" as a name for the oracle database - it's always "oracle", or "oracle database" in full.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp historically, users doesn't care about history, just what their current assumptions, however wrong you believe them to be, are. To fix the confusion, you need to fix the assumptions.

Comment: @Braiam, that's why we have synonyms.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp no. That's abusing the synonym system. "A tag synonym is usually a tag that has **exactly the same meaning as some other tag**, such as algorithm and algorithms" What you guys do, is a perversion of the english language calling that action synonymization, when it's actually "I'm too lazy to do the right thing and kill this tag".

Comment: @Braiam in this case, they *do* mean the exact same thing, so it is not abusing the synonym system to create a synonym.

Comment: @publicstaticvoidmain So I own Oracle.