# We shouldn't [microfocus] our tags so much

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

There's a company, **MicroFocus**, that has its own tag on Stack Overflow: [microfocus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microfocus), with 93 questions at this point.

1. The tag doesn't add anything useful to the question;
2. Questions related to MicroFocus are off topic;
3. Usually the questions tagged with this company name are also tagged with the actual framework the company produced, and that is how it is supposed to be;
4. If we allow this tag, others might get the idea to create other company-name tags as well.

Let's burninate it.

Comment: Just a wee note to say "sorry" if got a wee bit carried away - I edited out a number of said tags! I'm not yet "au fait" with the burninate process, but I looked and found the appropriate advice. I've calmed down, and will await the proper outcome of this request.

Comment: Please edit your question to answer the 4 questions about [Criteria for Burnination](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination/324071#324071).

Comment: *Questions related to MicroFocus are off topic;* Huh? Why?

Comment: *If we allow this tag, others might get the idea to create other company-name tags as well.* Not allowing a tag because it might inspire other tags to be created is a weird argument. You can predict the future?

Comment: @rene I don't expect questions about a corporate entity to be on topic, or I'm missing something?

Comment: @Braiam that might be true but I have yet to see the many questions it attracts about the company and the argument that MicroFocus is only about the company and can't mean anything else.

Comment: @rene the only company tag that was allowed, was Sony's, and that's because the company actually followed and made sure to answer questions with the tag. That is the only reason for exception. In this case, the company seems to have several products and *not providing any housekeeping services towards the tag*. I believe that exceptions need to have some kind of reasoning behind it. There's no benefit of having the tag, unlike sony's.

Comment: Well, in retrospect, I disagree with points two and four. I guess I got a little too excited to burninate :D.

Answer (score 4):

I disagree with the "kill with fire" approach articulated so far<sup>1</sup>.  I think there's an obvious cleanup/retagging effort that could easily be done.

While there is an argument to be made to ban all corporate tags, the examples given so far ([apple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple) and [microsoft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft)) are of a completely different scope and scale<sup>2</sup>.  Possibly more relevant is [oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle).  See discussions [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377079/the-oracle-vs-oracledb-tag) and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274858/what-is-wrong-with-the-oracle-tag). That tag remains, despite being a company name, because it is sometimes necessary for disambiguation of SQL questions.

More than half (48) of the 87 questions are also tagged [cobol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cobol).  There is no [microfocus-cobol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microfocus-cobol) tag.  Possibly, these 48 questions should be retagged with that more specific tag (or [microfocus-visual-cobol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microfocus-visual-cobol)).  The next most common tag, [alm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alm), could similarly become [microfocus-alm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microfocus-alm).

While certainly this company has a suite of products, I'm seeing a lot of overlap and not a huge amount of off-topic posts.

The OP did not evaluate the burnination criteria; I doubt the answer is no for all the questions, particularly the one about relevant information.  The [cobol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cobol) post alone does not provide enough information for a post about MicroFocus Visual COBOL.

I do not think the tag is actively causing harm or attracting a lot of off-topic, low quality posts.

Save the fire-burning for bigger problems.

---

<sup>1</sup> At the time I wrote this answer, there was another answer and associated comment which used the words "kill it with fire" without any detail exactly "how", and did not express any intent to rename, merge, synonymize, or in any other way present a nuanced approach to cleaning up this tag. I am not opposed to this tag going away, but I believe a retag, disambiguation, or other approach is preferable to simple deletion, which "burn it" implies.

<sup>2</sup> The references to these companies were in the other answer that was deleted. I view a tag for MicroFocus's suite of products similarly to the way a [ms-office](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-office) tag might apply to several related, integrated products.

Comment: Is microfocus cobol so different than the actual cobol?

Comment: Depends on what you define as "actual COBOL".  There are differences in MicroFocus COBOL and GNU COBOL.  Which one is "actual"?   Should SQL questions just say "SQL" without specifying Oracle (a company name) flavoring vs. MySQL vs. Microsoft (another company name) SQL, etc?  I'm no COBOL expert, but I'd expect a set of "standard" commands and custom add-ons for the usual things like string parsing, date formats, etc. that may differ.

Comment: I expect a spec and then implementations of that spec, like C, C++, etc.

Comment: So how do you tag questions about features which are not part of the spec, and differ between implementations?

Comment: For C, just C. If there's a case where the spec doesn't cover, it's undefined. In SQL, implementations differences are called "extensions", and in the case of ms sql, they call their implementation T-SQL.

Comment: So your answer to [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41238940/microfocus-cobol-commands-cobinit-cobcall-and-cobtidy-are-throwing-errors-in-my) about MF Cobol specific commands should be, "it's undefined"?

Comment: If the specs don't define the behavior that implementations should follow, it's by definition undefined. I don't really want to get lost in semantics. Anyways, tags should mean something on topic, a corporate entity is not on topic for SO last time I checked. If you have a better name for tags about these topics, suggest that instead.

Comment: I believe I did that in my answer. You are welcome to propose other ones that you think are a better fit.

Comment: "I disagree with the "kill with fire" approach articulated so far." nope, you also disagreed with the removal of the tag. So, which is it? Removing the tag by replacing with others or not removal of the tag?